# How move a view to the nearest edge of the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, view

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what (Facebook) Messenger's ChatHeads does after the user stops interacting with the view, its just snaps to the nearest edge.

I also tried using the overshoot animation but I couldn't get it to move to the nearest edge so I removed it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: a screenshot would help us to help you

Comment: I would like something similar to the way this behaves https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_-4U5w30Mc

Comment: Have you seen its source code? https://github.com/webondevices/react-chat-head/blob/master/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it once using this Medium tutorial. Worked like a charm.

[Chat Heads Bubbles: Credit: @kevalpatel2106](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064)

Comment: Thanks but I already have this. This doesn't explain how I could get this animation working.